# Can not seem to figure out why my matrix multiplication function is not working

Tags: javascript, matrix

```
let multiply = function(a, b) {
  let c = [];
  for(let row = 0; row < 4; row++){
    for(let col = 0; col < 4;col++){
      for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        c[col + (4*row)] += a[i][row] * b[col][i];
      }
    }
  }
```

The function takes two four by four matrixes and outputs an array of length 16. It does not seem to be giving me the correct array.

Comment: is ```const a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]];``` a valid input for ```a``` ? It would be nice to know what a valid input looks like :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
let multiply = function(a, b) {
  let c = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
  for(let row = 0; row < 4; row++){
    for(let col = 0; col < 4; col++){
      for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        c[col + (4*row)] += a[row][i] * b[i][col];
      }
    }
  }
  return c;
}
```

Notice that you need to initialize the output array and your `row x col` multiplication was wrong; you need:
`a[row][i] * b[i][col]`
instead of
`a[i][row] * b[col][i]`
The function should also return the resulting array.
You can give it a try using JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fxLpucg/

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).